# Django - Clean a field, refer to a Related object

Tags: python, django, foreign-key-relationship

I have groups and people, I want that inside a group there could not be more than one person with the same name... but in different group it's ok... pretty easy. My code:

```
class Group(model.Model):
    name = models.CharField() #irrelevant

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=False)
    related_group = models.ForeignKey(Group)


    def clean(self):
        if self.related_group:
            for pip in self.related_group.person_set.all():
                if pip.name == self.name:
                    raise ValidationError("Name already exists in this Group")
```

I get this error:

```
RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /create/person/  # the url of creating the object
```

Person has no related_group.

I guess the problem is that I need to find a way to refer to the group (in the form )
thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use [`unique_together`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/options/#unique-together), then you won't need checks in your `clean` method.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=False)
    related_group = models.ForeignKey(BreadcrumbGroup)

    class Meta:
        unique together = [
            ('name',  'related_group'), 
       ]
```

Comment: It kinda works, but sadly, this raises an "Integrity Error" and not a "Validation Error", is there something i can do to raise a validation error? why in the first place it does not get the related_group it supposed to get?

Comment: If you are using model forms, it should validate the `unique_together` for you, unless you are excluding one of the fields from the form. Can you show your view?

Comment: @Alasdair You should include the usage of ```get_or_create``` and/or ```update_or_create``` in your answer to show how to create/update a Person.

Comment: @Alasdair I indeed did not add the group to my modelform, I fixe it yesterday (And added a costum clean method to validate it for me), thanks for your answer!

Comment: @schillingt I'm not sure I'd recommend the `get_or_create` approach, so I removed it from the answer, it might be better to add as a separate answer.  I think it should be possible to do the validation before the person is created/updated, so it shouldn't be necessary to use `get_or_create`.